# React Native NavigatorIOS won't re-render Component

Tags: react-native

I have a TabBar with multiple TabBar.Item components. Each TabBar.Item component has it's own NavigatorIOS.

Here's an example of my code for my `TabBar.js`

```
<TabBarIOS>
  <TabBarIOS.Item
    selected={this.state.selectedTab === "profile"}
    systemIcon={"most-viewed"}
    onPress={() => this.setTab("profile")}
  >
    <NavigationBar title="Profile" component={Profile} passProps={{ showFilter: this.state.showFilter }} />
  </TabBarIOS.Item>
</TabBarIOS>
```

Within my `NavigationBar.js`, I simply render out a `NavigatorIOS`

```
<NavigatorIOS
  ref="nav"
  initialRoute={{ ...this.props }}
  style={{
    flex: 1
  }}
/>
```

When a User clicks the `Filter` button, `this.state.showFilter` is updated in `TabBar`. It's then passed down into `NavigatonBar` correctly, the `render()` function inside of `NavigationBar` is executed however,

**At this point, my component won't re-render the component listed in `initialRoute` (Profile)**

Is there any way to achieve this? When clicking the Filter I need to set an optional variable inside of `Profile` to hide and show the Filter `Modal`

Comment: I don't know IOS, but this question seems like it provides a possible solution:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3249240/how-to-pop-a-controller-off-the-navigation-stack-without-using-the-navigation-ba

Comment: Thanks for the comment, this is more related to React Native (JavaScript) as appose to Swift/Objective-C (which is what's in the link you provided)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure whether there is a more elegant solution to this, but I have one that works.

I added the following code inside of `NavigationBar`:

```
shouldComponentUpdate(nextProps, nextState) {
    this.refs.nav.replace({...nextProps})
    return true;
  }
```

This will force a reload of the `initialRoute` component.